# How to install tophat in Debian?

Tags: debian, samtools

I have tried searching and trying everything. I have bowtie, samtools and libbam-dev installed in my system. While running `./configure` I am getting this error:

```
checking for bamlib... configure: error: We could not detect the
bam libraries (version  or higher). If you have a staged bam library
(still not installed) please specify $BAM_ROOT in your environment
and do not give a PATH to --with-bam option.
```

How do I solve this error and install tophat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAMtools must be proparly packaged, otherwise TopHat cannot use them. So:

1. Build BAM from the source first. Get it at http://samtools.sourceforge.net/.
2. Choose the BAM installation folder (I refer it as **install** below).
3. Copy all C header files to **install**/*include/bam*.
4. Copy *libbam.a* to **install**/*lib*.
5. Place *samtools* binary on your path.
6. For TopHat, try *./configure* --with-bam=**install**
7. If this does not work for some strange reason, try also export BAM_ROOT=**install** before running *./configure*.